# Unique count for one column - split by delimiter and unique count for substring

Tags: r, split, count, substring, distinct

I would like to unique count x value for splitting column x by '|' and substring left 2 character in R.

```
df <-data.frame(id = c(11,22,33,44),
                x = c(NA,'cna|cnb|jpa|usa|jpb|usb','kra|krb|kru|usb|usa','jpa|jpu|epa|epb|usa|woa|cna|jpu'))

> df
  id                               x
1 11                            <NA>
2 22         cna|cnb|jpa|usa|jpb|usb
3 33             kra|krb|kru|usb|usa
4 44 jpa|jpu|epa|epb|usa|woa|cna|jpu
```

I want to get below.

```
  id    count
1 11    0
2 22    3
3 33    2         
4 44    5
```

- line 1 is 0
- line 2 is cn,jp,us(3 data)
- line 3 is kr,us(2 data)
- line 4 is jp,ep,us,wo,cn(5 data)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another approach. It is not as compact and simple as `akrun`'s answer, but it doesn't depend on any libraries:

```
df$count <- sapply(df$x, function(varx){
    strs <- unique(sapply(unlist(strsplit(varx, "|", fixed = T)), function(string){
        substr(string, 1, 2)
    })) 
    length(strs[!is.na(strs)])
})
```

**Output:**

```
  id                               x count
1 11                            <NA>     0
2 22         cna|cnb|jpa|usa|jpb|usb     3
3 33             kra|krb|kru|usb|usa     2
4 44 jpa|jpu|epa|epb|usa|woa|cna|jpu     5
```

Comment: A bit shorter: `sapply(sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$x),'\\|'), substr, start = 1, stop = 2), function(x) length(unique(na.omit(x))))`

Comment: @Jaap, a little more shorter (one less sapply) would be `sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$x), "|", fixed = TRUE), function(x) length(unique(substr(na.omit(x), 1, 2))))`

Comment: great~! The solution is so simple! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse`.  We split the elements in 'x' and expand to long format with `separate_rows`, `mutate` the 'x' by taking only the first two characters (`substr`), grouped by 'id', find the `count` of unique non-NA elements using `n_distinct`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    separate_rows(x) %>% 
    mutate(x= substr(x, 1, 2)) %>%
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarise(count =  n_distinct(x[!is.na(x)]))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#     id count
#  <dbl> <int>
#1    11     0
#2    22     3
#3    33     2
#4    44     5
```